# Query get_posts array must contain at least 3 posts that have specific ACF meta value

Tags: wordpress, filter, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I am trying to extract posts that contain no less than 3 records that contain a certain value in an ACF meta key.

I have a list of employees that we are displaying on the site using:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'team_member',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'   => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 20, 
));
```

However I now need to introduce a query that ensures that at least 3 ladies are displayed within this list at any given time. I have setup an acf field `gender` with values `male` and `female` to capture this, but am unable to get the correct meta value query structure in place.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'team_member',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'   => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 20, 
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'gender',
            'value'     => 'female',
            'compare'   => '>'
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a different direction and created to seperate queries that I combined, this seemed to work fine.

```
$male_posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'team_member',
    'meta_key'=> 'gender',
    'meta_value'=> 'male',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'  => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 15, 
));
$female_posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'team_member',
    'meta_key'=> 'gender',
    'meta_value'=> 'female',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'  => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 3, 
));
$all_posts = array_merge( $male_posts, $female_posts );
$all_posts_ids = wp_list_pluck( $all_posts, 'ID' );
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'post__in'  => $all_posts_ids,
    'post_type'  => 'team_member',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'  => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
```